# google custom search api complex search terms

Tags: parameters, google-custom-search

The program I am writing needs to execute complex search queries. 
An example would be

(blue AND jeans AND NOT (cheap || expensive)) .
How can I do this. I know there are parameters 
such as hq and exclude and orTerms (or just the boolean operator),
but I don't know how to combine them, or if they can be combined for that matter.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters are described [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list).

> *q* (string)
>   The search expression.
>
> *exactTerms* (string)
>   Identifies a phrase that all documents in the search results must contain.
>
> *excludeTerms* (string)
>   Identifies a word or phrase that should not appear in any documents in the search results.
>
> *orTerms* (string)
>   Provides additional search terms to check for in a document, where each document in the search results must contain at
>   least one of the additional search terms.

And the different Boolean Operators are described [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#booleanOperators).

> **AND**
>  includeTerms=(phrase%20one).(phrase%20two)
>
> **NOT**
>  q=key1%20(-key2)
>
> **OR**
>  excludeTerms=key1|key2
>  orTerms=key1|key2
>
> **()**
>  lr=-(lang_fr|lang_it)

By that you could call `q=john%20doe&orTerms=wikipedia|imdb` and this will result documents containing `john AND doe AND ( wikipedia OR imbd )`.

Something what I did not expect was `q=&exactTerms=(john).(doe).(wikipedia)` (46 results) returns the same as `q="john%20doe%20wikipedia"` (46 results). I thought it would result the same as `q="john"%20"doe"%20"wikipedia"` (153000 results). So it is sometimes more a CONCAT than an AND operator or `exactTerms` is simply not able to support multiple keywords.

Comment: I never checked the xml api since it's for commercial users only, but it seems they offer the same functionality regarding the orTerms. I deleted my answer, since it's not offering much after yours. Feel free to remove the reference you make to my answer

Comment: Thx, it's very helpful

Comment: @mgutt: Do you know if orTerms boost the ranking of the query too? If I include 100 terms in the orTerms, will it rank the document with the most overlapping terms first?