# How to use parameters in Google Programmable Search?

Tags: python, google-api-client, search-engine-api

This question has been asked a few times, but never with any real answers.

[Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420800/google-custom-search-api-complex-search-terms)

[Here is another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852939/how-to-use-exactterms-and-excludeterms-with-google-custom-search-json-api)

What I am trying to figure out is how to put multiple terms into a parameter, for example

search for exactly "Cat" AND "Dog" not "Cat Dog" using the exactTerms parameter
same type of thing for orTerms and excludeTerms.

If anyone has used this service before let me know, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1) is not very clear at all.